# how to substitute a javascript yahoo weather api call property with a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, assign

This is a script that work fine and reads yahoo weather api

```
<script>
  var callbackFunction = function(data) {
    var windy = data.query.results.channel.wind;
    alert(windy.chill);
  };

</script>

<script src="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select wind from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='chicago, il')&format=json&callback=callbackFunction"></script>
```

But I need to substitute a variable into
    var windy = data.query.results.channel.wind;
such as

```
var select = "results";
var windy = data.query.select.channel.wind;
```

Nothing I do works.
I defined the var inside and outside the function, no difference.
I used +select+  and it too caused an error.
My goal is to have a page with a drop down menu for the user to select a weather item and to give the selection to the query above, hence the need for a variable.
Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var select = "results";
var windy = data.query[select].channel.wind;
```

When using the `[]` notation you could pass a dynamic property name as per your requirement.

Comment: That worked exactly as you described. Many thanks. Now I can work on my dropdown menu. Hurray

Comment: If this answer helped you resolve the issue you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it.